# Castle Windsor Dependency Injection in Base Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I'm using `Castle Windsor` in an `ASP.Net MVC` project, which is set up following the [Castle Windsor documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/mvc-tutorial-part-1-getting-windsor.md)

My `controller` inherits from `BaseController` to avoid repeating code:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public HomeController(IAService aService)
    :base(aService){}

    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = DoSomething();
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

`BaseController` inherits from the MVC `Controller` class:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAService _aService;

    public BaseController(IAService aService)
    {
        _aService = aService;
    }
    protected string DoSomething()
    {
        _aService.GetData();
    }
}
```

`Service` and `IService` are defined as:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public Service()
    {
    }
    public string GetData()
    {
        return "Something";
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    string GetData();
}
```

`IService` is registered in an Installer as implemented by `Service` with `LifeStylePerWebRequest`.

I've put a `breakpoint` on the constructors of both `HomeController` and `BaseController` and the `Service` is being injected as inspected at that point, but the problem is that when `GetData()` is called, it fails because `_aService` is `null`, presumably having already been disposed by CW.

I've also tried defining `_aService` as a `protected` member rather than `private`, with no difference in the outcome.

Have I got the wrong Lifestyle set for `Service`, am I doing something wrong, or have I missed something really obvious?

Comment: To confirm - it's not null when it's injected?

Comment: No, it is not null in the constructor(s) when it is injected.